# Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[PaginationComponent -> PaginationConfig]

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to add a pagination to my Angular application as explained in this link:

[Go to "Content switching"](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/pagination)

I did this:

In *app.module.ts*:

```
import { PaginationModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/pagination';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
       @NgModule({
    ]
})
```

In *app.component.html*:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-12">
      <div class="content-wrapper">
      <p class="content-item" *ngFor="let content of returnedArray">{{content}}</p>
      </div>
      <pagination [totalItems]="contentArray.length" (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)"></pagination>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

In *app.component.ts*:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { PageChangedEvent } from 'ngx-bootstrap/pagination';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  contentArray = new Array(90).fill('');
  returnedArray: string[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contentArray = this.contentArray.map((v: string, i: number) 
   => `Content line ${i + 1}`);
   this.returnedArray = this.contentArray.slice(0, 10);
 }

 pageChanged(event: PageChangedEvent): void {
    const startItem = (event.page - 1) * event.itemsPerPage;
    const endItem = event.page * event.itemsPerPage;
    this.returnedArray = this.contentArray.slice(startItem, endItem);
   }
 }
```

But when I compile I have the following error:

> core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(RootModule)[PaginationComponent -> PaginationConfig]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[PaginationComponent -> PaginationConfig]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for PaginationConfig!
>   Error: StaticInjectorError(RootModule)[PaginationComponent -> PaginationConfig]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[PaginationComponent -> PaginationConfig]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for PaginationConfig!
>       at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:8896)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)

Any idea on what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's should be this right ?

```js
import { PaginationModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [PaginationModule.forRoot(),...]
})
```

Comment: That's it... just found the solution a second ago. Why sometimes you need to add the forRoot()? Sorry for the question... newbie in Angular...

Comment: when you use forRoot() and it will be app wide